# How can I raed(distract) annotaion creater information with PyPDF2?

Tags: python, annotations, data-annotations, pypdf, pdfcreator

I read(distracted) annotation text using PyPDF2 as below.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")

for page in reader.pages:
    if "/Annots" in page:
        for annot in page["/Annots"]:
            subtype = annot.get_object()["/Subtype"]
            if subtype == "/Text":
                print(annot.get_object()["/Contents"])
```

But I don't know how to read who made the annotation using PyPDF2.

Would you help me with this?

I tried to solve the problem chaning code one to many times.(for ex. Text => User)

Of course it didn't work.

Comment: As I understand PyPDF2 is outdated. Have you tried with `pypdf`? Check https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/annotations.html